# Как разбить строку на слова в python?

Tags: python-3.x, строки, split, re

Данна строка, надо разбить её на отдельные слова. Проблема в том, что метод s.split() не подойдёт, ведь иначе пришлось прописывать бы с каждым символом отдельно. Была еще такая идея:

```
import re
s = str(input())
words = re.split(r'(\W+)', s)
print(words)
```

Но при s = 'abc45def', words = ['abc45def'], а надо 'abc', 'def'. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
s = 'abc45dEf'

words = re.findall(r'[a-z]+', s, flags=re.I)
print(words)
# ['abc', 'dEf']
```